# Block file in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I'm still really a amateur in IIS and I want to be able to block out this file (favicon.ico) from beeing requested.

I don't know where to go from this screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't block something from being requested but you can deny the response. In the **IIS** section of your screenshot click on **Request Filtering**. Then click the **URL** tab and add a rule such as `/favicon.ico`. This will force IIS to return a 404 for that URL.